# The Chart of Matrix Eigenvalues : Energy Levels

Tags: plotting, matrix

There is the possibility that this question may have been asked previously, but as we are unfamiliar with the nature of the chart below, we hope to seek a response to this query.

Consider a matrix as follows:

```
matrix = {{0.1 j, 0, 0, 0.2 j, 0}, {0, 0.1 j, 0, 0.2 j, 0}, {0, 0.1 j,
0, 0, 0.2 j}, {0.1 j, 0, 0, 0, 0.2 j}, {0, 0, 0.1 j, 0.2 j, 0}};
```

In any choice of `j` which must be chosen in the range of `[1,2,3,4]`, there is a set of eigenvalues (for this matrix we expect `5` eigenvalues for each `j` separately), we are going to draw a chart similar to

[image]

in which the vertical axes shows eigenvalues magnitude (from the lowest one to the largest for various j's). (however the real eigenvalues are not `1, 2, 3` for `j=1` for the above defined matrix the plot is just a schematic picture of what we wish to have). Also (`for j=1 and j=2`) for instance there is a condition in which degeneracy is governed or the different between continuous eigenvalues for a special `j` is less than `10^-3`, with a command same as:

```
Union[Eigenvalues[matrix] // N, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-3 &)]
```

How we can draw this wish and with the last condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear[Hma];

n = 5;

Hma[j_Integer] = {{0.1*j, 0, 0, 0.2*j, 0}, {0, 0.1*j, 0, 0.2*j, 0}, {0, 0.1*j,
     0, 0, 0.2*j}, {0.1*j, 0, 0, 0, 0.2*j}, {0, 0, 0.1*j, 0.2*j, 0}};

data1 = Flatten[Table[Thread[{j,
       Eigenvalues[Hma[j]]}],
     {j, n}], 1] // Chop;
```

With your condition

```
data2 = Flatten[Table[Thread[{j,
       Union[Eigenvalues[Hma[j]], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 10^-3 &)]}],
     {j, n}], 1] // Chop;
```

There are no eigenvalues eliminated by your condition

```
Length[data1] == Length[data2]
```

> True

```
ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["J No.", Medium, Bold], Style["Values", Medium, Bold]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @mr.0093, this is _very_ easy to find in the documentation....

Answer (score 0):

I am not too clear about your last condition, however the following code could yield an output CLOSE to what you have in mind:

```
Hma[j_] = {{0.1*j, 0, 0, 0.2*j, 0}, {0, 0.1*j, 0, 0.2*j, 0}, {0, 
    0.1*j, 0, 0, 0.2*j}, {0.1*j, 0, 0, 0, 0.2*j}, 
       {0, 0, 0.1*j, 0.2*j, 0}}; 

ListPlot[Table[Evaluate[Eigenvalues[Hma[j]]], {j, 1, 5, 1}], 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {Style["J No.", Large, Bold], 
   Style["Values", Large, Bold], Style["", Large, Bold]}, 
 Ticks -> Automatic, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Large]]
```

Each colour denotes a distinct J. There is one eigenvalue for each J that seem very close to zero, so the last dot signifies these small values.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the defrerences of eigenvalues (for example for j=1) is same! the EigenValues@Hma/.j->1= {0.3, -0.273205, 0.1, 0.0732051, 3.93535*10^-17}, but there is no minus eigenvalues for j=1!

Comment: Don't know what u mean.....the blue dot signifies J=1, and does go below zero in the plot.. Moreover you could modify the code.

Comment: Besides, thanks for your try but I think there is a misunderstanding. Above j=1 must be put pertinent eigenvalues (eigenvalues related to j=1 in the matrix)!

Comment: these numbers   {0.3, -0.273205, 0.1, 0.0732051, 3.93535*10^-17} must be put above the j=1,

Comment: Whati is "pertinent: eigenvalue? If you are after the magnitude, use "Abs"

Comment: the list :  {0.3, -0.273205, 0.1, 0.0732051, 3.93535*10^-17} are pertinent eigenvalues to j=1.

Comment: the vertical axes shows eigenvalues magnitude (from the lowest one to the largest for various j's). (however the real eigenvalues are not 1, 2, 3 for j=1 for the above defined matrix the plot is just a schematic picture of what we wish to have)

Comment: @thils, he wants all of the eigenvalues for a given j stacked above eachother at j on the first axis. Your first axis does not currently show the value of j.

Comment: @ Marius Ladegard  Got your point, gd that Bob fixed it!